# Is it safe to use process.env.NODE_ENV in my app code?

Tags: node.js

I would like to change the behaviour of my app based on whether I'm in production or development.

My approach is to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to a string, either `'production'` or `'development'` and to access this variable in my app code. Simple example:

```
imgSrc = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'img1.svg' : '/app/img/img2.svg'
```

Is this safe / best practice? Any alternative approaches?

Comment: What does "safe" mean? What are you afraid of?

Comment: You could use something like that, or look at an app configuration package like [`config`](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) that enables implementing environment-specific configurations.

Comment: Well, i do that. Nobody told me it's not safe yet. You shouldn't worry too.

Comment: I think I heard that it was bad practice to expose this variable in the app code. But can't remember.

Comment: Isn't there a way of doing this so that webpack does the if/else logic and changes the source code on that basis?

Comment: @tbking Having alternate code paths for different environments isn't really a good idea. It makes it too easy to introduce bugs that can only be identified in production.

Answer (score 0):

It's not inherently unsafe, but it is bad practice.

Ideally your code shouldn't need to know anything about what environment it's running in.

Some better approaches..

1. Have an environment variable defining the base path for images. Set
   it appropriately for dev and production. Your code may then look
   something like this...

   imgSrc = `${process.env.BASE_PATH}img2.svg`;

   or
2. Try to make sure your dev and production paths match. This is
   generally a better approach. The less variation there is between
   production and development, the more likely you are to catch bugs
   before they reach production.